# Como instalar um Windows Service sem Setup?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Tenho um projeto de Windows Service no Visual Studio em C#, porém, preciso instalar este projeto a partir de linhas de código, **sem** utilizar o [Installutil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx) do *console* e nem o *Setup* do Visual Studio.

Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 13):

Pode-se usar a classe [`ManagedInstallerClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (responsável por lidar com a funcionalidade do [Installutil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx)), mais especificamente, o método [`InstallHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass.installhelper(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    if (System.Environment.UserInteractive) {
        if (args.Length > 0) {
            switch (args[0]) {
                case "-install": {
                   ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                   break;
                }
                case "-uninstall": {
                   ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

<sub>[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072345/1608936)</sub>

Exemplo de uso:

- Instalar: `meuProjeto.exe -install`
- Desinstalar: `meuProjeto.exe -uninstall`